# My href link is not working on my wordpress button

Tags: php, wordpress

I am editing a wordpress theme and I'm trying to edit an existing button to take me to other area of my site on the final page of a submit form (my form goes across 5 pages). I looked at the other 4 pages on how they link to the following page and used this as a basis for my final page however it refuses to work. I enabled debug mode and it gave the following error.

"Warning: Use of undefined constant esc_html_e - assumed 'esc_html_e' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"

I'm simply trying to add a href to the following button

```
 <input type="submit" class="wpb_btn-info wpb_btn-small wpestate_vc_button  vc_button" id="edit_calendar" value="<?php esc_html_e('Save', 'wprentals') ?>">
        <?php
        $ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce( "wprentals_edit_calendar_nonce" );
        print'<input type="hidden" id="wprentals_edit_calendar_nonce" value="'.esc_html($ajax_nonce).'" />    ';
                
        ?>
        
        </div>
```

Anyone know why href does not work on this button?

Answer (score 0):

Try `_e` instead. Also you dont need to do `input="hidden"` for your once as the create does that for you automatically. You just need to verify it or call on it during your validations or post-submit (read the examples on the link below for a more detailed explanation).

```
<?php
$ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'wprentals_edit_calendar_nonce' );
?>

<input type="submit" class="wpb_btn-info wpb_btn-small wpestate_vc_button  vc_button" id="edit_calendar" value="<?php _e( 'Save', 'wprentals' ); ?>" />
```

***Reference:***

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_nonce/

Comment: Thank you Aliqua I’ll try it the moment I’m home.